# im trying to capture client PC name in my web project, i found gethostname() but it captures only host name, Any help will be appreciated.! Thank You

Tags: javascript, php

these are the methods which i tried..

```
$device_name = gethostname();
$device_name = getenv('COMPUTERNAME');
$device_name = php_uname();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "client pc name"?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What's the difference between "pc name" and "hostname"? Give an example, because it's not clear what you mean. Also, this can only capture the name of the device where the PHP code is running, it can never get information about a device which made a HTTP request to your PHP code, if that's what you're thinking of. A HTTP request doesn't contain that information. (You can get the public IP address of the requestor in that scenario, but that's about all.). And how is JavaScript relevant here? You've only shown PHP code.

Comment: You cannot capture the client's PC name with PHP. It can only grab what the client sends, usually found in the User Agent String, and PC name is never sent. You might be able to get it with javascript, but I have a feeling that it can't due to security controls.

Comment: @aynber It used to be possible, if you were prepared to use ActiveX. But obviously that's not an option anymore. So you're right, getting the local device details via JS in the browser is not feasible.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.